# How to Control CSS Class Visiblity From WordPress Admin Panel based on Tax Terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Can you please let me know if it is possible to control Visibility of some html elements like  and  which are loading from an specific taxonomy terms meta data? I For Example I have two metadata as "Make" and "Year" for my custom post and I would like to ONLY hide the meta (Make and Year) for my post with specific Custom Taxonomy term = "Hback" (Not for any other terms)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question is not very detailed but I think you are talking about hiding parts of the markup for a post. If that is the case then [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) should be what you want.

```
if (!has_term('Hback','tax-slug')) {
  // markup that does not show for 'Hback'
}
```

'tax-slug' is the taxonomy-- a WordPress core taxonony like 'post_tag' a custom taxonomy that you or a plugin has created. You need to provide a third parameter containing the post ID or the post object if you are not meaning to check for the current post in a loop.

Comment: Hi s_ha_dum,sorry for confusion and thanks for your comment. OK let me explain a little bit. what I want to do is rendering CPT's title, and two meta box values (Make, Year). I am displaying all the post based on their taxonomy terms perfectly but in some taxonomy terms like "hback" I didnt have any information to fill the meta data. and right now thy are displaying empty in the page (Only meta data section). like Make = <> Year =<>. so I thought I may can handle this from administrator panel. Adding a meta data (check-box) to Custom Taxonomy to hide or display the ONLY custom post meta  data?

Comment: Can someone help me about this one please?

Comment: [Edit] your _question_ with the additional details, please.

Comment: ... but I am pretty sure I just told you how to selectively show or hide meta data based on the taxonomy terms, which even after your clarification still sounds like what you want. You don't need a checkbox. Just show the data if it is present.

Comment: Oh,so you mean it will automate the process? I got your point now! and thank you. but I need also make them to be visible/hide explicitly! is it possible to do this by administrator select option like checkbox? Once again thanks for your time and support.

Comment: Yes, you can create checkboxes that will let you show and hide items explicitly. That sounds like a different question to me. The Stack Exchange sites like "one question per question". It is certainly a more involved problem. Please search the site for related questions before posting a question of your own.